# Programatically save node fields if fields is autocomplete?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have created a content type with 3 fields and my one field is node_refrence in this filed I am filling title of other node using node_refrence.

I am using this code.

```
> $node = new stdClass(); 
 $node->type = 'application';
> node_object_prepare($node);
> $node->title = "test title";
 $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
> $node->field_application_school[$node->language][]['target_id']  =
> 1373;
> $node->field_application_school[$node->language][]['target_type'] =
"node";
 node_save($node);
```

I need to  fill the entry  for `$node->field_application_school[$node->language][]['target_id']`, its not working.

Comment: target_id is used by the entity reference module, if you're using a different module (node_reference) it'll be something else. Maybe `nid`, but just check the module code to be sure

Answer (score 0):

@jsh I'd suggest to create a test node through the admin menu (i.e. node/add/content_type) then dpm/debug the $node object in that content type template and finally view the node and look through the object's output and see where your code differs from the object constructed by Drupal.